# How to consume rest API in eclipse dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

I'm trying to learn a lot about Eclipse Java.

I have done a lot of searching for how to display API data in Eclipse

I am very happy if there is information that can make it easier for me to know this method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are newbie to rest web services creation/consumption. Here is a tutorial link to understand the basics. 
 https://www.journaldev.com/9170/restful-web-services-tutorial-java.

you can develop rest web service using annotations like @path ,@consumes to specify the web service features. 
Also, there are some tools like **postman** available to access webservices via providing the web service resource URL eg: http://localhost:8080/person/getinfo .

I hope this helps :)